# When monitoring events on the client, is there a way to tell that the ajax is being redirected?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

When an jsf ajax is being redirected, the client receives a status code of success, responseCode of 200 and responseXML of null.   is there not a way for client to know that it is a redirect?

Comment: It's definitely in the `responseXML` (just check HTTP response in browser's HTTP traffic monitor). Otherwise JS couldn't perform the redirect job anyway. How exactly are you trying to obtain it so that it's `null` instead of a concrete XML document? Apparently you was trying to obtain it in a wrong way.

Comment: I simply do a alert like below and the responseXML is displayed as null:        alert('status=' + ajaxData.status + '\n' + 'responseCode=' + ajaxData.responseCode + '\n' + ajaxData.responseXML);

Comment: Yes, the browser traffic monitor is showing the redirect XML.  I'm just not getting in from the ajaxData.responseXML.  ajaxData.responseXML is not null if ajax is not redirected.

Comment: Works fine for me. Show a MCVE and tell JSF impl/version.

Comment: Found the problem.  I was trying to add an additional element in the <partial-response> that will let me know that the redirect was caused by session timeout.  When I was adding it, I added the element as a sibling of <partial-response>.  I change it to be a child and it starts to work.  Why adding it as sibling causes reponseXML to become null is a bit beyond my.  But once I changed it to be child, responseXML returns the XML correctly.

Comment: Okay. I'll post an answer anyway, showing the normal approach, so that the question is still useful to others searching for the same :)

Comment: I'm implementing a stay login feature on my site that will auto re-login after session has timeout.  I'm having problem on how should I handle Session/View Scope beans that have already expired/gone even after the re-login completed normally.  So, when ajax is fired after session timeout, the relogin will not resolved expired bean issue.  Should I open a new question for this?

Comment: Stateless views or `<o:enableRestorableView>` can aid in this.

Comment: it is an existing site with lots of jsf/jsp.  Not sure I can change all to stateless views.  Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal circumstances, the `responseXML` should definitely not be `null`. Given that, you could check as follows whether the current JSF ajax response represents a redirect and also where it would point to.

```
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data) {
    if (data.status == "complete") {
        var redirect = data.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("redirect");

        if (redirect.length) {
            var url = redirect[0].getAttribute("url");
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```